# Edit DT in shiny doesnt edit the values

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app where I am trying to load the app with some standard values for the user to understand the template and then allow them to add /edit/delete rows. I am able to add rows without any issues so far. But the modify seems to be giving issues.So when I try to modify the frequency value for any selected row I can change the number in the text box but when I click on save it doesn't update. Also at times the values in impressions column are updated by the value of the selected rows channel name. See screenshot below. I tried to edit value for frequency for channel 2 and look at the value for impressions before and after.

Before edit

After edit

Also the delete doesnt seem to delete any selected rows. Could someone help me what might be wrong here.

server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
## shinysky is to customize buttons
library(shinysky)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(shinyalert)
library(dplyr)

rm(list = ls())
useShinyalert()
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  
  ### interactive dataset 
  vals_trich<-reactiveValues()
  vals_trich$Data<-data.frame(Partner = c("Channel 1", "Channel 2","Channel 3"),
                              Impressions = c(7727063, 4741286, 105585800),
                              TotalReach = c (0, 0, .0),
                              Frequency = c(2, 2.6, 3.7),
                              Assumptions = c (.41, .45, .5),
                              pcReach = c (0, 0, 0),
                              #gg = c (.5, .5, .5),
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  #vals_trich$Data<-readRDS("note.rds")
  
  #### MainBody_trich is the id of DT table
  output$MainBody_trich<-renderUI({
    fluidPage(
      hr(),
      column(6,offset = 6,
             HTML('<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example" style = "padding:10px">'),
             ### tags$head() This is to change the color of "Add a new row" button
             tags$head(tags$style(".butt2{background-color:#231651;} .butt2{color: #e6ebef;}")),
             div(style="display:inline-block;width:30%;text-align: center;",actionButton(inputId = "Add_row_head",label = "Add", class="butt2") ),
             tags$head(tags$style(".butt4{background-color:#4d1566;} .butt4{color: #e6ebef;}")),
             div(style="display:inline-block;width:30%;text-align: center;",actionButton(inputId = "mod_row_head",label = "Edit", class="butt4") ),
             tags$head(tags$style(".butt3{background-color:#590b25;} .butt3{color: #e6ebef;}")),
             div(style="display:inline-block;width:30%;text-align: center;",actionButton(inputId = "Del_row_head",label = "Delete", class="butt3") ),
             ### Optional: a html button 
             # HTML('<input type="submit" name="Add_row_head" value="Add">'),
             HTML('</div>') ),
      
      column(12,dataTableOutput("Main_table_trich")),
      tags$script("$(document).on('click', '#Main_table_trich button', function () {
                   Shiny.onInputChange('lastClickId',this.id);
                   Shiny.onInputChange('lastClick', Math.random()) });")
      
    ) 
  })
  
  #### render DataTable part ####
  output$Main_table_trich<-renderDataTable({
    DT=vals_trich$Data
    datatable(DT,selection = 'single',
              escape=F) })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Add_row_head, {
    ### This is the pop up board for input a new row
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "Add a new row",
                          textInput(paste0("partner", input$Add_row_head), "Partner"),
                          numericInput(paste0("impressions", input$Add_row_head), "Impressions",0),
                          numericInput(paste0("reach", input$Add_row_head), "TotalReach:",0),  
                          numericInput(paste0("frequency", input$Add_row_head), "Frequency:",0),  
                          numericInput(paste0("assumption", input$Add_row_head), "Assumptions:",0), 
                          numericInput(paste0("reach_pc", input$Add_row_head), "pcReach:",0), 
                          actionButton("go", "Add item"),
                          easyClose = TRUE, footer = NULL ))
    
  })
  ### Add a new row to DT  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    new_row=data.frame(
      Partner=input[[paste0("partner", input$Add_row_head)]],
      Impressions=input[[paste0("impressions", input$Add_row_head)]],
      TotalReach=input[[paste0("reach", input$Add_row_head)]],
      Frequency=input[[paste0("frequency", input$Add_row_head)]],
      Assumptions=input[[paste0("assumption", input$Add_row_head)]],
      pcReach=input[[paste0("reach_pc", input$Add_row_head)]]
    )
    vals_trich$Data<-rbind(vals_trich$Data,new_row )
    removeModal()
  })
  
  
  observe({
    # We'll use these multiple times, so use short var names for
    # convenience.
    c_num <- input$control_num
    
    # Change the value
    updateNumericInput(session, "inNumber", value = c_num)
  })
  
  ### save to RDS part 
  observeEvent(input$Updated_trich,{
    print(vals_trich$Data)
   calc<- vals_trich$Data 
   print(calc)
   calc <-calc %>% mutate(TotalReach = Impressions/Frequency,pcReach = (TotalReach/(input$inNumber/Assumptions)*100))   
   print(calc)
    vals_trich$Data <-calc
    DT=vals_trich$Data
    datatable(DT,selection = 'single',
              escape=F)
    
    saveRDS(vals_trich$Data, "op.rds")
    shinyalert(title = "Saved!", type = "success")
  })
  
  
  
  ### delete selected rows part
  ### this is warning messge for deleting
  observeEvent(input$Del_row_head,{
    showModal(
      if(length(input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected)>=1 ){
        modalDialog(
          title = "Warning",
          paste("Are you sure delete",length(input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected),"rows?" ),
          footer = tagList(
            modalButton("Cancel"),
            actionButton("ok", "Yes")
          ), easyClose = TRUE)
      }else{
        modalDialog(
          title = "Warning",
          paste("Please select row(s) that you want to delect!" ),easyClose = TRUE
        )
      }
      
    )
  })
  
  ### If user say OK, then delete the selected rows
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    vals_trich$Data=vals_trich$Data[-input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected]
    removeModal()
  })
  
  ### edit button
  observeEvent(input$mod_row_head,{
    showModal(
      if(length(input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected)>=1 ){
        modalDialog(
          fluidPage(
            h3(strong("Editing Values"),align="center"),
            hr(),
            dataTableOutput('row_modif'),
            actionButton("save_changes","Save changes"),
            tags$script(HTML("$(document).on('click', '#save_changes', function () {
                             var list_value=[]
                             for (i = 0; i < $( '.new_input' ).length; i++)
                             {
                             list_value.push($( '.new_input' )[i].value)
                             }
                             Shiny.onInputChange('newValue', list_value) });")) ), size="l" )
      }else{
        modalDialog(
          title = "Warning",
          paste("Please select the row that you want to edit!" ),easyClose = TRUE
        )
      }
      
    )
  })
  
  
  
  
  #### modify part
  output$row_modif<-renderDataTable({
    selected_row=input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected
    old_row=vals_trich$Data[selected_row,]
    row_change=list()
    for (i in colnames(old_row))
    {
      if (is.numeric(vals_trich$Data[[i]]))
      {
        row_change[[i]]<-paste0('<input class="new_input" value= ','"',old_row[[i]],'"','  type="number" id=new_',i,' ><br>')
      } 
      else if( is.Date(vals_trich$Data[[i]])){
        row_change[[i]]<-paste0('<input class="new_input" value= ','"',old_row[[i]],'"',' type="date" id=new_  ',i,'  ><br>') 
      }
      else 
        row_change[[i]]<-paste0('<input class="new_input" value= ','"',old_row[[i]],'"',' type="textarea"  id=new_',i,'><br>')
    }
    row_change=as.data.table(row_change)
    setnames(row_change,colnames(old_row))
    DT=row_change
    DT 
  },escape=F,options=list(dom='t',ordering=F,scrollX = TRUE),selection="none" )
  
  
  
  ### This is to replace the modified row to existing row
  observeEvent(input$newValue,
               {
                 newValue=lapply(input$newValue, function(col) {
                   if (suppressWarnings(all(!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(col)))))) {
                     as.numeric(as.character(col))
                   } else {
                     col
                   }
                 })
                 DF=data.frame(lapply(newValue, function(x) t(data.frame(x))))
                 colnames(DF)=colnames(vals_trich$Data)
                 vals_trich$Data[input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected]<-DF
                 
               }
  )
  ### This is nothing related to DT Editor but I think it is nice to have a download function in the Shiny so user 
  ### can download the table in csv
  output$Trich_csv<- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("Trich Project-Progress", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data.frame(vals_trich$Data), file, row.names = F)
    }
  )
  
})
```

ui.r

```
#
# This is the user-interface definition of a Shiny web application. You can
# run the application by clicking 'Run App' above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
# 
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinysky)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(shinyalert)
useShinyalert()
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Calculator"),
  ### This is to adjust the width of pop up "showmodal()" for DT modify table 
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                            .modal-lg {
                            width: 1200px;
                            }
                            '))),
 # helpText("Note: Remember to save any updates!"),
  br(),
  ### tags$head() is to customize the download button
 numericInput("inNumber", "Number input:",
              min = 1, max = 330000000, value = 20000000, step = 1000000),
  useShinyalert(), # Set up shinyalert
  uiOutput("MainBody_trich"),actionButton(inputId = "Updated_trich",label = "Save"),
 tags$head(tags$style(".butt{background-color:#230682;} .butt{color: #e6ebef;}")),br(),
 downloadButton("Trich_csv", "Download in CSV", class="butt"),
))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of the delete part, you are deleting columns, not rows due to a missing comma in the square brackets (added here):

```
observeEvent(input$ok, {
        vals_trich$Data=vals_trich$Data[-input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected,]
        removeModal()
    })
```

In case of the edit part, you are also missing a comma in the square brackets (added here):

```
DF=data.frame(lapply(newValue, function(x) t(data.frame(x))))
            colnames(DF)=colnames(vals_trich$Data)
```

```
        vals_trich$Data[input$Main_table_trich_rows_selected,]<-DF
```